# How to choose a p.d. matrix $\Sigma$ s.t. $x^T\Sigma Mx>0$ for all $x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Assume $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a real square matrix, which is fixed and we also assume that its eigenvalues all have positive real parts. In particular, it is invertible.

Then my question is how to choose $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, symmetric and positive definite (that is $x^T \Sigma x >0$ for all $x$), such that the latter property carries over to the product $\Sigma M$, that is we want
$$ x^T \Sigma M x >0 $$ for all $x$. (Maybe we can also replace the inequality with $\geq$ if this allows nicer solutions.

Now of course the first idea one would have here is to set $\Sigma =  PM^{-1}$ for some symmetric, positive definite $P$. However, it is unclear to me whether this is possible, i.e. if this product could yield a symmetric p.d. matrix for some $P$. (If $M$ is symmetric it is trivially true but this case is not of interest)

I also tried to write $x$ as a linear combination of (possibly complex) eigenvectors of $M$, but this also did not get me very far.

So, is there a general way to determine a solution here, or does someone at least know some conditions for which a solution would be possible ?

Comment: You may solve the Lyapunov equation $\Sigma M+M^T\Sigma=A$, where $A$ is any positive definite matrix you like (such as $I_n$). The solution is $\Sigma=\int_0^\infty e^{-tM^T}Ae^{-tM}dt$. It can also be expressed as $\operatorname{vec}(\Sigma)=(M^T\otimes I_n+I_n\otimes M^T)^{-1}\operatorname{vec}(A)$.

Comment: @user1551 thank you, I did not now this equation. If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it. Also, do you happen to know how to determine the converse, i.e. whether a given $\Sigma$ (and $M$) still given will result in a p.d. matrix?